# So i got the error code error CS1022 i just dont know how to fix it cause i cant find the error, probaly deleted something cause i was in a rush

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i got the error code error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected i just dont know how to fix it cause i cant find the error, probaly deleted something cause i was in a rush

Heres the Code:

`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveVelocity;
}


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}  `
```

Comment: You have mis-matched the braces. Delete the first `}` to fix it

Answer (score 1):

you are closing the `class` with a bracket `}` before you define the methods.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float speed;

   private Rigidbody2D rb;
   private Vector2 moveVelocity;


   void Start()
   {
       rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
   }

   void Update()
   {
       Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
       moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
   }
   void FixedUpdate()
   {
       rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
   }
}
```